# Postgresql - Refer to the previously calculated column

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have some tables like these.

```
create table programming_language(
id                         smallserial primary key,
name                       text not null,
initial_users              integer not null,
initial_release            date not null
);

create table usage_data(
id                                   smallserial primary key,
language_id                          integer references programming_language(id),
percent_users_change                 decimal(5,2),
increase_or_decrease                 boolean default False, -- false indicates decrease
survey_year                          integer not null
);
```

Now each programming_language has an initial number of users as given in initial_users of the table programming_language. The usage_data has percent_users_change column which gives us the percentage increase or decrease in the number of users from the previous years. Whether it is a decrease or increase is given by the column increase_or_column. Now i have a need to query and find the number of users in each survey_year. I wrote the following query to achieve this but i am not able to because you cannot refer to the variable in the same select query.

```
select language_id,case when increase_or_decrease=True then percent_users_change+(lag(previ,0)  over(partition by language_id order by survey_year))
              when increase_or_decrease=False then percent_users_change-(lag(previ,0) over(partition by language_id order by survey_year))
              end as previ
from usage_data;
```

**A Sample Data:**

```
+----+-------------+----------------------+----------------------+-------------+
| id | language_id | percent_users_change | increase_or_decrease | survey_year |
+----+-------------+----------------------+----------------------+-------------+
|  1 |           1 |                   10 | True                 |        1991 
|  2 |           1 |                  7.5 | True                 |        1993 |
|  3 |           3 |                 12.5 | True                 |        1996 |
|  4 |           4 |                 8.75 | True                 |        1996 |
+----+-------------+----------------------+----------------------+-------------+
```

For example, For the language 1, if the initial users are 10, for 1991, I want it to be 11(10+10% of previous year) and after 1992 it should be 11.825(11+7.5% of 11) and so on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the percentage changes can be calculated from the initial users

```
pct_change(i) = init_users * prod_from_0_i(pct_change)
```

where `pct_change` is represented as a 1 +/- `percent_users_change / 100`

e.g.

```
# for language 1, init_users = 10 
1991 (change 10%)  -> 10 * (1.10) = 11 
1993 (change 7.5%) -> 10 * (1.10)(1.075) = 11.825
```

For this we need a Product aggregate function, which isn't implemented in SQL, however, we can implement it taking logarithms, we can apply the `SUM` aggregate function.

This works because of the following identities:

```
log(xy) = log(x) + log(y)
```

generalizing this to a series of xs

```
log(xs) = log(x0) + log(x1) + ..., where x0,x1,... <- xs
        = sum(log(x | x <- xs))
```

and

```
x = exp(log(x))
```

i.e. `exp` & `log` are inverse functions.

Also, note that `log` is undefined for 0 & negative values.

combining these two identities, we get:

```
exp(SUM(ln(x) | x <- xs, x > 0)) === prod(xs)
```

Thus, we can write the query as:

```
WITH united AS (
    SELECT 
      EXTRACT(YEAR FROM initial_release) yr
    , id
    , initial_users :: NUMERIC users
    , 1.0 change
    FROM programming_language

    UNION ALL

    SELECT 
      survey_year yr
    , language_id id
    , null
    , case when increase_or_decrease 
        then 1 + (percent_users_change / 100.0)
      else 1 - (percent_users_change / 100.0) end change
    FROM usage_data
)
SELECT yr, id, 
FIRST_VALUE(users) OVER w * EXP(SUM(LN(u.change)) OVER w) users
FROM united u
WINDOW w as (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY yr ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)
```

where first the initial data and later usage data are unified and the `change` column is calculated, and then `users` for successive years are calculated from the initial `users`.

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked! Can you please explain why exp(sum(ln(column))) gives us product aggregate